# How to insert .load() into ajax modal window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I cant figure it out.
**index.php script (working 100%):**

```
function openBlockEditor(block, nick) {
    var blockInfo = $.ajax({
        url: "Element/BlockEditor.php",
        type: "GET",    
        data: 'block=' + block + '&nick=' + nick,
        dataType: "html"
    });

    blockInfo.done(function(msg) {
        $("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog(
        {
            show: {
            duration: 100
            },
            hide: {
            duration: 100
            }
        });
        $('.ui-dialog-title').html("Block editor")
    });
    blockInfo.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Please report this: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

**Element/BlockEditor.php:** (this page contains modal window content)

```
Test:<div id="BuildedBox"></div>

<?php
    if($MACHINE_digger==1){$MACHINE_digger="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"buttonBuild('$block_id', 'Pomp', '$nick')\">[BUILD]</a>";}else{$MACHINE_digger="<strike>[BUILD]</strike>";}
    if($MACHINE_waterpomp==1){$MACHINE_waterpomp="<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"buttonBuild('$block_id', 'Pomp', '$nick')\">[BUILD]</a>";}else{$MACHINE_waterpomp="<strike>[BUILD]</strike>";}
?>

Digger:<?php echo $MACHINE_digger; ?><br/>
WaterPomp:<?php echo $MACHINE_waterpomp; ?><br/>

<a class="ub" id="BlockEditorSaveButon" href="#">Refresh</a>
<script>
$(function() {
      $("#BlockEditorSaveButon").click(function() {
         $("#show_planet_realtime").load("../in/GameEngine/RealTimeRender.php?p=<?php echo $nick; ?>")
      })
    })
            function buttonBuild(id, building, nick)
            {
                $("#BuildedBox").load("BlockEditor/build.php",{
                    id:id,
                    building:building,
                    nick:nick
                });
            }
</script>
```

In this page, is not working my `buttonBuild()` function. I also tried to put it in **index.php** below function `openBlockEditor()` but ain't working.. Is there possible way to connect `buttonBuild()` with a `openBlockEditor()`??? The function `openBlockEditor()` calls a modal window with info in it and function `buttonBuild()` must perform `.load()` action inside that modal window.

Comment: Add the two functions in one js file and include it in index.php.

Comment: Or you can add the Block editor click event inside a function and call it after the ajax request completion.

Comment: Thank you for response, but i have tried your both ways, but its not working tho..

Comment: Is the onclick working? I mean, check whether buttonBuild() is called onclicking the link.

Comment: can you give me example? i am new in ajax :(

Comment: Post the console log. That might give some idea.

Comment: where find that console log???

Comment: firebug result if using firefox or press f12 & select console if using chrome.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonBuild is not defined play;:1
onclick` so this means i must add `onclick` ?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of your code?

Comment: okay, but later, cuz now i am going home from work..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nt7q3/1/ here is my script

Comment: It's working. Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bnafL

Comment: omg it really working ;) thanks for showing that `alert` function :) i have written wrong `.load()` filepath :D but there is another problem - the link wont pass variables to my javascript.. it shows empty fields.. :(

Comment: oh.. i just changed from `_GET` to `_POST` and it works!!! thanks man ;)

Comment: I checked it and the values are sent in the headers.

Comment: yes it's in post method. Glad it finally worked.

Comment: yeah ^^, thanks again, for showing that simple `alert()` code!